# Как сделать случайную переменную?

Tags: php

Наример

```
<?php
$a ="link"; //содержит точный текст
$b = "link2";//содержит точный текст
echo "Вывести в браузер рандомно a и b переменной c";
?>
```

Comment: Заголовок с телом вопроса какие-то перпендикулярные..... Напишите подробно что нужно

Comment: что то мне кажется, тут достаточно будет `echo time()%2 ? "link1" : "link2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $a ="link" . rand(0, 10000); // случайнное значение от link0 до link10000
  $result = md5(rand());
  /*
  Возможные способы как получить случайнную переменую типа `string`
  $result = md5(rand());
  $result = sha1(rand());
  $result = hash("sha256", rand());
  $result =  uniqid();
  Способ получить случайнную переменую типа `string` длинной `n`
  */
  $b = $result;
  // $b = getName(12);
  echo "Вывести в браузер рандомно $a и $b";

  function getName($n) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $randomString = '';
  
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        $index = rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1);
        $randomString .= $characters[$index];
    }
  
    return $randomString;
  }
?>
```

Comment: вот результат. http://t9155861.beget.tech/test/ наверно нерпавильно меня понял. я хочу чтобы два значения a и b выводились случайно. например сначала a потом b. вывести переменной c

Answer (score 1):

Добавляйте переменные в массив и используйте функцию array_rand(). При желании можно массив ещё и перемешать с помощью shuffle().

```
$arr = array($a, $b);
$c = $arr[array_rand($arr, 1)];
```